# android -notlong eclipse: "Invalid resource directory name"

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I try to refactor/rename my layout/large forlder to

> > layout-xlarge-mdpi-notlong

Then Eclipse return this error

> > Invalid resource directory name

I really don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

because **-mdpi-notlong** is not supported in android.

Comment: Ok! But, why can I not be able to select the density AND the ratio of each type of devices? :(

Comment: In the link you provided, where does it exactly say that it is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

You can not rename the name of resource folders the way you want. Android keeps it standard. You should read this link.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html